# Spring AOP not injecting transaction in @Transactional method from a proxied class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

We have an application that we are migrating from Spring Boot 1 and Hibernate 3.6.8 to latest Spring Boot 2 and Hibernate 5.2.17.

Everything seems to be ok, except that there are some methods that we are calling and are not getting a transaction injected. Like this service:

```
@Service
public class BreakFixProcessorBO extends BaseProcessorBO  {

    @Transactional  
    public void process(String xml){
        [...]
```

It's called from this other class:

```
@Service
public class BreakFixAmerInternalConsumer extends BaseConsumer {

    private BreakFixProcessorBO breakFixProcessorBO;

    @Autowired
    public BreakFixAmerInternalConsumer(BreakFixProcessorBO breakFixProcessorBO) {
        this.breakFixProcessorBO = breakFixProcessorBO;
    }

    @Override
    protected void proccess(String messageBody) {
        breakFixProcessorBO.process(messageBody);
    }
```

Many other code call repositories use @Transactional, and many services also use @Transactional, and many of them work correctly. Except that some of them aren't, and we can't find any difference.
I have been reading a lot of documentation on how transactions work on proxied classes. And it seems that when the class implements an interface behaviour changes a bit.
So I tried to create an interface just with the method:

```
public interface BreakFixProcessorBO_TransactionTest  {
    void process(String xml);
}
```

And have the service implement it:

```
@Service
public class BreakFixProcessorBO extends BaseProcessorBO implements BreakFixProcessorBO_TransactionTest {
```

Does not matter what we do. We are having the following exception on some specific services:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3505) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1427) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:147) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:96) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:922) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at d.s.a.bizo.processor.BreakFixProcessorBO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e171e8a9.process(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
 at d.s.a.consumer.BreakFixAmerInternalConsumer.proccess(BreakFixAmerInternalConsumer.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
 at d.s.a.consumer.BaseConsumer.onMessage(BaseConsumer.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
 at d.s.a.consumer.BreakFixAmerInternalConsumer.onMessage(BreakFixAmerInternalConsumer.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor218.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
 at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:182) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
 ... 10 common frames omitted
```

It seems that Spring AOP is proxying successfully the instance... but no transaction is created.
I tried Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, and it behaves the same.

Our PlatformTransactionManager is defined together with our datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@RefreshScope
public class DBConfiguration extends DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean annotationSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        annotationSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        annotationSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("d.s.a");
        annotationSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return annotationSessionFactoryBean;
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return createDataSource(propertyResolver);
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

And our application uses most auto-configuration available:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
        exclude = {
                JmsAutoConfiguration.class,
                CamelAutoConfiguration.class
        })
@ImportResource({"classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "d.s.a")
public class OurApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(System.getProperty("debug") != null) { //-Ddebug=true should be a feature
            args = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length+1);
            args[args.length-1] = "--debug";
        }
        SpringApplication.run(OurApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The applicationContext.xml is just some old task runner definitions we haven't migrated yet.
What are we missing, or is it a Spring bug?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
   @Override
   @Transactional
    protected void proccess(String messageBody) {
        breakFixProcessorBO.process(messageBody);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did when I created the interface.

Comment: Did you mark it @Transactional ?   The code above does not have it

Comment: Yes, I did. Used \@Transactional on the implementation. Its the first piece of code in the question, but then I had added @Override.
I didn't include the full implementation after the interface to not "duplicate" code in the question, as I thought that saying that I have added "implements" the interface to the already present \@Transactional method would be sufficient.

Comment: I don't see it in your `BreakFixAmerInternalConsumer` class.  Please try adding it there (at the Service level)